# Can ScheduledThreadPool be use to accept different type of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

Working on the problem where I have 3 cash counters serving the number of customers. Every counter take 1 sec to process 1 item apart from third counter which takes 2 sec to process each item. (e.g. customer A with 5 items on counter one will take 5 seconds to complete), Customer B with 3 items on counter C will take  6 seconds. Every customer has different time of joining the queue.
I used the `ScheduledExecutorService` to create number of threads equivalent to cash counters.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
```

Now my runnable implementation checks the number of items and runs loops accordingly.

I am submitting the number of task depending on number of customer.

```
scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable(),Timetojoin, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

How do I assign different priorities to 3 threads created by executor service. As my last counter(thread) takes 2 second to process each item.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide custom `ThreadFactory` to the `ExecutorService`. Your `ThreadFactory` will allow you to create new Threads that will suit your needs.

`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, ThreadFactory threadFactory)`

More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), in the doc.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, but all threads created via  `ThreadFactory' will be of similar type. Is it possible to have different behavior for just single Thread and others have common behavior?

Comment: Thread factory creates new threads. Parameters of such threads depends on implementation of such factory. Factory doesn't have to produce the same threads at all.

Comment: Sorry didn't completely understood, does that mean we have create 2 of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor one with implementation A and another with implementation B

 ScheduledExecutorService poolA = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1,new RetailThreadFactory(new TrainerRegister()));
 ScheduledExecutorService poolB = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2,new RetailThreadFactory(new NormalRegister()));

class RetailThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory{
 Runnable r;
 RetailThreadFactory(Runnable r){
  this.r=r;
 }
 public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
  Thread t= new Thread(r);
  return t;}}